# Threads not running at same time?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Firstly, I know the title is not exactly "unique" but its a specific problem, please read before marking it as a duplicate.

I have created an application that will visit a webpage and sign in to an account on multiple threads. Now.. I have testing this a few times but it comes out without weird results. It picks a random account from a dictionary and tries to login with it (multiple threads).

Here is the bot handler which creates a class for each thread

```
class BotHandler
{
    private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> _que;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, BotInfo> _accounts;
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Bot> _Bots;

    private readonly Random _random = new Random();
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> Que => _que;

    public BotHandler()
    {
        _que = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        _accounts = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, BotInfo>();
        _Bots = new Dictionary<int, Bot>();

        _que.TryAdd("username", new KeyValuePair<string, int>("add", 12));
    }

    public void LoadBots()
    {
        var config = Program.GetServer().GetConfigHandler();

        using (var dbConnection = Program.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
        {
            dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `_bot_accounts` WHERE `enabled` = '1'");
            var table = dbConnection.ExecuteTable();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                _accounts.TryAdd(_accounts.Count + 1, new BotInfo(
                    Convert.ToString(row["username"]), 
                    Convert.ToString(row["password"]),
                    DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(row["last_used"]), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
            }
        }

        Logger.Warn("Loaded " + _accounts.Count + "  bots.");

        for (int i = config.GetValueByKeyInt("_bot.bot_count"); i > 0; i--)
        {
            _Bots.Add(_Bots.Count + 1, new Bot(_Bots.Count + 1));
        }
    }

    public void StartBots()
    {
        foreach (var Bot in _Bots.Values)
        {
            Bot.Start();
        }
    }

    public KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetCurrentQue()
    {
        return _que.First();
    }

    public KeyValuePair<int, BotInfo> GetAccount()
    {
        var account = new KeyValuePair<int, BotInfo>();

        var randomlyOrdered = _accounts.OrderBy(i => _random.Next());

        lock (locker)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, BotInfo> entry in randomlyOrdered)
            {
                if (!entry.Value.Usable())
                    continue;

                account = entry;
            }
        }

        if (!CoreUtilities.IsDefault(account))
        {
            using (var databaseConnection = Program.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
            {
                databaseConnection.SetQuery("UPDATE `_bot_accounts` SET `last_used` = '" + 
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' WHERE `username` = '" + account.Key + "' LIMIT 1");
            }

            account.Value.LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
        }

        return account;
    }
}
```

Bot

```
using NLog;
using _Bot.Root.Core.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _Bot.Root.Base.Bots
{
    class Bot
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private readonly int _botId;
        private readonly Thread _botThread;

        private bool _working;
        private KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> _currentQue;

        private WebBrowser _browser;
        private bool _processing;

        private string _username;

        public Bot(int botId)
        {
            _botId = botId;

            _botThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnCycle));
            _botThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            Logger.Trace("BotThread #" + botId + " has been deployed.");
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _botThread.Start();
        }

        private void OnCycle()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!_working && Program.GetServer().GetBaseHandler().GetBotHandler().Que.Count > 0)
                {
                    StartWorking();
                }
            }
        }

        private void StartWorking()
        {
            if (_working)
            {
                return;
            }

            _working = true;

            if (_browser == null)
            {
                _browser = new WebBrowser()
                {
                    ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true
                };

                _browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            }

            _currentQue = Program.GetServer().GetBaseHandler().GetBotHandler().GetCurrentQue();

            if (CoreUtilities.IsDefault(_currentQue))
            {
                Logger.Error("Unable to find a que for thread #" + _botId + "");

                _working = false;
                return;
            }

            _browser.Navigate(StaticSettings.SIGNIN_URL);

            Application.Run();
        }

        private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_processing)
            {
                return;
            }

            _processing = true;

            try
            {
                var br = sender as WebBrowser;

                if (br.Url == e.Url)
                {
                    var url = e.Url.ToString();

                    if (_browser.DocumentText.Contains("Sign Out"))
                    {
                        Logger.Warn("Logged In: " + _username);

                        /*if (!url.StartsWith(StaticSettings.MAIN_URL + "/" + _currentQue.Key))
                        {
                            _browser.Navigate(StaticSettings.MAIN_URL + "/" + _currentQue.Key);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Logger.Info("[Thread #" + _botId + "] Preparing for " + _username + " to " + _currentQue.Value.Key.ToLower() + " " + _currentQue.Key);

                            HtmlElement marryButton = null;

                            foreach (HtmlElement element in br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
                            {
                                if (element.GetAttribute("data-original-title").ToLower() == _currentQue.Value.Key.ToLower())
                                {
                                    marryButton = element;
                                }
                            }

                            if (marryButton == null)
                            {
                                Logger.Error("Failed to marry " + _currentQue.Key + " on " + _username);
                                return;
                            }

                            marryButton.InvokeMember("click");

                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                            HtmlElement sendButton = null;

                            foreach (HtmlElement element in br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
                            {
                                if (element.InnerText == "Send" && element.GetAttribute("type") == "submit")
                                {
                                    sendButton = element;
                                }
                            }

                            if (sendButton == null)
                            {
                                Logger.Error("Failed to marry " + _currentQue.Key + " on " + _username);
                                return;
                            }

                            sendButton.InvokeMember("click");
                            sendButton.InvokeMember("click");

                            Logger.Info("[Thread #" + _botId + "] " + _username + " " + _currentQue.Value.Key.ToLower() + " " + _currentQue.Key);

                            _working = false;
                        }*/
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (url.StartsWith(StaticSettings.SIGNIN_URL))
                        {
                            foreach (HtmlElement element in br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
                            {
                                if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "alert alert-danger")
                                {
                                    Logger.Error("Something went wrong...");
                                    Logger.Error(element.InnerText);
                                }
                            }

                                var account = Program.GetServer().GetBaseHandler().GetBotHandler().GetAccount();

                            if (CoreUtilities.IsDefault(account))
                            {
                                Logger.Error("[Thread #" + _botId + "] Failed to find an account");
                                _working = false;
                                return;
                            }

                            _username = account.Value.Username;

                            Logger.Info("Logging In: " + _username);

                            HtmlElement usernameBox = null;
                            HtmlElement passwordBox = null;
                            HtmlElement loginButton = null;

                            foreach (HtmlElement element in br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                            {
                                if (element.GetAttribute("name") == "username")
                                {
                                    usernameBox = element;
                                }
                                else if (element.GetAttribute("name") == "password")
                                {
                                    passwordBox = element;
                                }
                                else if (element.GetAttribute("name") == "submit")
                                {
                                    if (element.GetAttribute("value") == "Login with Facebook")
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    loginButton = element;
                                }
                            }

                            if (usernameBox == null || passwordBox == null || loginButton == null)
                            {
                                Logger.Error("Failed to login with " + account.Value.Username);
                                return;
                            }

                            usernameBox.SetAttribute("value", account.Value.Username);
                            passwordBox.SetAttribute("value", account.Value.Password);

                            Logger.Trace("[Thread #" + _botId + "] Logging In: " + _username);

                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

                            loginButton.InvokeMember("click");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Logger.Trace("Redirecting back to " + StaticSettings.SIGNIN_URL);
                            _browser.Navigate(StaticSettings.SIGNIN_URL);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Logger.Error("Something went wrong..");
            }
            finally
            {
                _processing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so as you can see each "Bot" class has its own thread and then it visits the Sign Up URL, once it reaches the Sign Up URL it'll sign in with the random accountpicked from the dictionary.

I have sent logs to the console for when its logging in and when its logged in. The main issue is every account will log that its "Logging In" before it tells me its logged in, then I'll start getting "Logged In" logs? Surely it would all happen at the same time instead of waiting for all accounts to finish visiting the sign up page and clicking the login button?

Another issue is, not all accounts make it to inside. I'll show you what I mean.

```
  21:06:18 - Logging In: newabbie91
  21:06:18 - Logging In: bellav12
  21:06:19 - [Thread #2] Logging In: newabbie91
  21:06:19 - Logging In: ollielittle228
  21:06:19 - [Thread #6] Logging In: bellav12
  21:06:19 - [Thread #4] Logging In: ollielittle228
  21:06:19 - Logging In: alfiedallas704
  21:06:19 - [Thread #7] Logging In: alfiedallas704
  21:06:19 - Logging In: danman192
  21:06:19 - [Thread #5] Logging In: danman192
  21:06:20 - Logging In: alfiekru123
  21:06:20 - [Thread #9] Logging In: alfiekru123
  21:06:21 - Logging In: utuberouter774
  21:06:21 - [Thread #8] Logging In: utuberouter774
  21:06:21 - Logging In: cokepeter915
  21:06:21 - [Thread #1] Logging In: cokepeter915
  21:06:21 - Logging In: aaronalfie520
  21:06:21 - [Thread #10] Logging In: aaronalfie520
  21:06:22 - Logging In: alexmaster9134
  21:06:22 - [Thread #3] Logging In: alexmaster9134
  21:06:29 - Logged In: bellav12
  21:06:29 - Logged In: newabbie91
  21:06:30 - Logged In: ollielittle228
  21:06:30 - Logged In: alfiekru123
  21:06:30 - Logged In: alfiedallas704
  21:06:30 - Logged In: danman192
  21:06:30 - Logged In: utuberouter774
  21:06:30 - Logged In: alexmaster9134
  21:06:31 - Logged In: aaronalfie520
  21:06:33 - Logged In: cokepeter915
```

Do you see what happens? Not every account gets "Logged In" and its usually 9/10, it will rarely get 10 logged in, it will more often if I go for a lower amount of threads such as 4 or 6 but hardly ever 10/10 with 10 threads, mostly just 9/10

Can anyone explain this unusual behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I'm pretty sure you don't need the "locker" field at all.  Certainly not for enumerating the contents of a ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: The browser control uses async I/O, which in turn implicitly uses the thread pool, to handle the operations. You are seeing a combination of the thread pool having to create new threads as your operations progress, inconsistencies in the latency of the remote server, and of course the simple variation that always appears when dealing with the scheduling of threads (i.e. there's no guarantee of a round-robin scheduling, or even any fairness). See marked duplicate for additional discussion of the primary effect (thread pool).